# In simple project using Spring MVC controllers method calls three times

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

First, sorry for my English, i'm from Belarus, so, my English is not good enough.

So, my problem:
I am just trying to learn Spring MVC and decided to make a simple project in IntelliJ IDEA.
Issue is that method, that processes requests calls three times.

Controllers code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UsersListController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String usersList(ModelMap model) {
        UserService service = new UserService();
        service.createNew("test", "test", "test", 0, Role.admin);
        model.addAttribute("users", service.getAll());
        System.out.println(service.getAll().size());
        return "usersList";
    }
}
```

usersList.jsp code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
    <c:out value="${user.name}"/>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Class UserService just services User objects, concretely it adds new User, delete, change and other typical operations.

So, i expect to see a single "test", but i get: "test test test" (not enough reputation to post an image)

Any ideas, what should i do?

P.S. Class users - a simple class:

```
public class User {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private int age;
    private Role role;
//...constructors, setters and getters
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `service.createNew(` method?

Comment: there seems to be a problem with  your service class, rest seems good to me.

Comment: It seems you have collection of users model.addAttribute("users", service.getAll()); That's why you see multiple "test"

Comment: service.getAll().size() what does it give to you?

Comment: if i add System.out.println(service.getAll().size()); in method usersList(..) in controller, i'll get at the beginning "1", then will appear "2" and "3". So, it told me, that method usersList(..) in my controller calls again and again.

Comment: Sorry, still don't know how to add code into a comment and have no reputation to answer my own questions :)
Here is code of service.createNew(...)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pux95j7560ws0ck/Screenshot%20from%202014-07-07%2019%3A38%3A18.png

Comment: And here is code of method userDao.save(..)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cn5nx7jrc1bwunx/Screenshot%20from%202014-07-07%2019%3A37%3A05.png

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov yeah, in a fact, I add a collection as an attribute, but, firstly, it is a collection with a single element, and secondly, if I'll add an a system.out.println(..) in method usersList(..), I'll see, that it calls 3 times

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct but your method

```
service.createNew("test", "test", "test", 0, Role.admin);
```

probably return 3 users.Nothing else.Please check your createNew() method or you can post your service method here.Thanks

Comment: Frankly, the method returns nothing (`void`). Please post a comment when you don't have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The сontroller method can be called three times when using `Intellij IDEA` (*when the application starts*) - because of the server configuration `"After launch"` setting.

You can try unselecting it:

[image: screenshot from server configuration]